simple javascript code linked with flask not working
Home.html file:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Home</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{url_for("static",filename="css/css.css")}}">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to recipe book</h1>
<p>{{length}}</p>
<script>
const amount = {{length}};
console.log(amount);
</script>
</body>

</html>

main.py Flask python file:
#,redirect,url_for,send_from_directory,
from flask import Flask,render_template
import os
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/")
def home():
    parent  = r"C:\Users\khait\Desktop\Website\Recipe_Book\static\images"
    everything = os.listdir(parent)
    images = []
    for i in everything:
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(parent,i)):
            images.append(os.path.join(parent,i))
    length = len(images)
    return render_template("Home.html",images=images,length=length)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)`

i was just tryna use the length variable in my html. and it throws these errors in relation to this line: "const amount = {{length}};" and this line "console.log(amount);":
Error 1:
Property assignment expected.javascript
Error 2:
Declaration or statement expected.javascript
I am aware many similar questions have been asked on this but i looked through them and couldn't find an answer to my problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

You are trying to render the value on HTML page using JavaScript ? as you can do it without JavaScript as well by simply using the  {{length}} which you have implemented already .

As the above answer states. I can see that you have a syntax error regarding the usage of pipe | and comma ,. try this

const amount = {{ length | tojson | safe }};

safe : Will ensure that the content is not auto-escaped by Jinja2.
<script>
const amount = {{ length | tojson | safe }};
console.log(amount);
</script>

Tell me if you are still facing the error.

you need to ensure the value is rendered correctly as a js variable. You can use {{ length | tojson }}
<script>
const amount = {{ length | tojson }};
console.log(amount);
</script>


const amount = {{length , tojson}};
i wrote this bc there was another error htat said , was expected instead of | but that didn't remove the other problems

tysm it worked.

I have found 2 issues here.
The first one being <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{url_for("static",filename="css/css.css")}}">
There is a syntax issue, instead of using " at all times, try using ' as well because the program will mix them up otherwise. Here is the correct syntax:
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{url_for('static', filename='css/css.css')}}">

Second is that try wrapping the {{Length}} in Quotes "{{Length}}" to ensure that the javascript interpreter recieves a a string that represents the numerical value of Length.
Another method that makes it safer is using tojson but then you might have to adjust some things in your python code:
<script>
const amount = {{ length | tojson }};
console.log(amount);
</script>


okay tyvm. I will try these things and see if they fix it

amazing that fixed it. Can u just quickly explainn why that worked exactly. Why did I need quotation marks around the flask variable. The explanation you gave b4 left me a bit confused

Thats how JS reads the code and its mainly a syntax thing. By wrapping it in the quotes it makes it represent a numerical value

and what if it's a list i wanna respresent, that has strings inside it. the outside quotations mark will mess it up so how would i fix that?

const list = {{images | tojson}};
like this line shows same errors as b4 when i don't add the quotation marks. {images is an array of strings}

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'Breakfast' (at (index):13:17) and iyt says this when i put the quotation marks around it bc the array becomes this:                            const list = "["Breakfast.png", "Dessert.png", "Dinner.png", "Lunch.png"]";
